# How to improve image detail quality for mobile apps? (too blurry)

Tags: mobile, iphone, interface-design

What is the best file type to use in mobile apps?

I am developing an iphone app and I am using images with the same frame as the views with 72 dpis in a format file `.png` but when the detail is more complex (rounded corners or little dots in a circle) the images get very blurry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 2):

DPI is irrelevant. Ignore that. All that matters is pixel dimensions. Make sure you are making them at the dimension they will be used. Ie, if it's going to be 30px x 30px on the iPhone, make your image 30px x 30px. For retina, you'll want to make a second version at 60px x 60px.

PNG files are fine. But use whatever makes sense for your particular needs.

As for being 'very blurry' we'd likely need to see an example of what you mean to be of much more help.

Comment: I can't post images as I don't have 10 points of reputation. And I am already doing what you are saying.

Comment: Post your images elsewhere on the internet and link to them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798000/how-to-improve-uiimage-detail-quality-too-blurry?noredirect=1#comment24246165_16798000

Comment: Can be specific as to what you find 'blurry'? As far as I can see, those look typical of small details on a screen. You only have so many pixels to work with at those sizes.

Comment: In the first image the little circles in a circular line and the corners of the buttons are clearly blurry.

Comment: Those little circles appear to be smaller than a pixel. There's just not much you can do about that short of going into the image and tweaking things pixel-by-pixel. Screens are simply low resolution devices so fine detail at that size is going to inherently look that way.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are going to use `.png` files it would be good to compress the files for performance.  I have not had any image quality issues yet and I use [tinypng](http://tinypng.org/)